# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ArrayIndexOutOfExceptions in multiplying two matrices

Tags: java, neural-network

Trying to implement Neural Network in java and getting the above error, I have tried and googled a lot but I'm not able to get any solution.
Driver class:

```
public class Driver {
    static double [][]X ={
            {0, 0},
            {1, 0},
            {0, 1},
            {1, 1}
    };
    static double [][] Y = {
            {0},{1},{1},{0}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NNMain nn = new NNMain(2,10,1); // 2,10,1

        List<Double> output;

        nn.fit(X, Y, 50000);  

        double [][] inputMatrix = {  
                {0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}
        };
        for(double d[]:inputMatrix)
        {
            output = nn.predict(d);
            System.out.println(output.toString());
        }

The error is occurring while trying to multiply two matrices:

    public static Matrix multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(a.r, a.c);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.r; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.c; j++) {
    
                double sum=0;
                for(int k=0; k < a.c; k++)
                {
                    sum  += a.data[i][k] * b.data[k][j];  // ERROR HERE
                }
                temp.data[i][j]=sum;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Here the fit method is calling multiply function which is defined above in another file. I have tried changing the for loop conditions <= 0 or 1 but I'm unable to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure a’s column count (a.c) is always equal to b’s row count (b.r) which is a condition for matrix multiplication?

Comment: Yes, I got it, I have added a condition to check it and unfortunately it is going there but I really need to multiply them and now I'm wondering how to proceed it further !

Comment: Can you check if the condition is met if you swap the two matrices?

Comment: //Matrix hiddenMatrix = Matrix.multiply(w_ih, inputMatrix);


Matrix hiddenMatrix = Matrix.multiply(inputMatrix, w_ih);


Commented code is the one which was originally written, I have tried swapping it but still not working. Thanks for the suggestions though !

Comment: I guess you have to figure out how to fix the dimensions of your input. If this answers your original question of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException pls mark the answer as correct. Thanks!